# JavaFX Label in GridPane not extending

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, gridpane

I'm currently making a little JavaFX application.
In this application, I created a Label and wanted to stretch itself in both directions.
The Label is placed inside a GridPane and I tried all Methods I know, including the `Double.MAX_VALUE` Method, which in my opinion doesn't seem to be very elegant and also worked sometimes in a false way. Below you see the result I get:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        GridPane gp = new GridPane();
        gp.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.RED, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, new BorderWidths(3))));

        Label label = new Label("Some text that could be longer");
        label.setFont(new Font(20));
        label.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
        label.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.rgb(34, 35, 36), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        label.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.GREEN, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, new BorderWidths(3))));


        // Commands that don't look like to work
        GridPane.setHgrow(label, Priority.ALWAYS);
        GridPane.setFillWidth(label, true);
        GridPane.setVgrow(label, Priority.ALWAYS);
        GridPane.setFillHeight(label, true);

        ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints();
        cc.setFillWidth(true);
        cc.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        cc.setPercentWidth(100);

        RowConstraints rc = new RowConstraints();
        rc.setFillHeight(true);
        rc.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        rc.setPercentHeight(100);
        // end


        gp.add(label, 0, 0);
        gp.getColumnConstraints().add(cc);
        gp.getRowConstraints().add(rc);


        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(gp, 800, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I don't know what to do else, because none of the Methods above worked for me. In multiple examples, they didn't even worked once.

Comment: You also have to make the label cover more than one column.

Comment: See: `void add(Node child, int columnIndex, int rowIndex, int colspan, int rowspan)` from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html).

Comment: @Sedrick In the sample code, there's only one column, so there's no need to make the label span multiple columns. Presumably the OP just wants it to fill its cell in the grid horizontally.

Comment: @James_D, Thanks! I didn't notice.

Comment: If the `GridPane` only has one row and column, I would suggest using a different Parent Node.

Answer (score 3):

By default, a `Label` has its `maxWidth` set to `Region.USE_PREF_SIZE`, so it cannot grow wider than its preferred size. Set the `maxWidth` to be unbounded using

```
label.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

Among your other settings, you only need to set the `hgrow` to `ALWAYS`, which you can do either with the static method, or via the column constraints:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        GridPane gp = new GridPane();
        gp.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.RED, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, new BorderWidths(3))));

        Label label = new Label("Some text that could be longer");
        label.setFont(new Font(20));
        label.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
        label.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.rgb(34, 35, 36), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        label.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.GREEN, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, new BorderWidths(3))));
        
        label.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);


        GridPane.setHgrow(label, Priority.SOMETIMES);

        // Can use the following instead of the previous line:

        // ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints();
        // cc.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        // gp.getColumnConstraints().add(cc);


        gp.add(label, 0, 0);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(gp, 800, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok I understand, that makes sense. But why do the commands in my code don't do exactly this ? (The lines between the two comments)

Comment: @Alex Because the grid pane won't size the label bigger than the max width. (That's what "max width" means.)

Comment: Also, when I set a maxHeight or maxWidth to a parent pane, it iss just getting ignored and a child with a Double.MAX_VALUE gets outside. Thats another Problem that I can't handle

Comment: layouts are free to size their children to whatever they deem okay - pref/max/min are just hints. What each does, is explained exactly in its java doc :)

Comment: @Alex I don't understand what that means. The size of the parent pane is controlled by *it's* parent, attempting to respect its min, pref, and max sizes. I suggest you reread the [layout documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/package-summary.html)